# Add google Sign-In with SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, google-signin, swiftui

I am trying to add google sign-in with swiftUI whith UIKitViewController, and for some reason I have difficulties showing the button does not appear in style

The signIn and the button works perfect but at some point the style of the button stopped appearing

I'm adding the button in a uikit viewcontroller, because I couldn't think of another way to handle the Google delegate

Here's the preview https://ibb.co/tYhx62b

```
//
//  GoogleSignInButtonView.swift
//
//  Created by Ivan Schaab on 11/09/2019.
//  Copyright © 2019 Ivan Schaab. All rights reserved.
//
import GoogleSignIn
import SwiftUI

struct GoogleSignInButtonView: View {

    @EnvironmentObject var lvm: LoginViewModel

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Spacer()
            GoogleButtonViewControllerRepresentable { (token, user) in
                // Google Login Success
                // Now do Backend Validations
                self.lvm.loginOauth(token: token, user: user)
            }
            Spacer()
        }.frame(alignment: .center)
    }
}

class GoogleButtonUIKitViewController: UIViewController {

    var signInButton = GIDSignInButton()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().clientID = Constants.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID
        self.view.addSubview(signInButton)

        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance()?.presentingViewController = self

        // Automatically sign in the user.
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance()?.restorePreviousSignIn()
    }
}

struct GoogleButtonViewControllerRepresentable: UIViewControllerRepresentable
{
    let vc = GoogleButtonUIKitViewController()
    var googleResponse: (String, User) -> Void

    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> GoogleButtonUIKitViewController {
        return vc
    }
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: GoogleButtonUIKitViewController, context: Context) {}
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(vc: vc, googleResponse: googleResponse)
    }

    static func dismantleUIViewController(_ uiViewController: GoogleButtonUIKitViewController, coordinator: GoogleButtonViewControllerRepresentable.Coordinator) {
        print("DISMANTLE")
    }

    class Coordinator: NSObject, GIDSignInDelegate  {
        var foo: (String, User) -> Void
        init(vc: GoogleButtonUIKitViewController, googleResponse: @escaping (String, User) -> Void) {
            self.foo = googleResponse
            super.init()
            GIDSignIn.sharedInstance()?.delegate = self
        }

        func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInFor googleUser: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: Error!) {
            if let error = error {
                if (error as NSError).code == GIDSignInErrorCode.hasNoAuthInKeychain.rawValue {
                    print("The user has not signed in before or they have since signed out.")
                } else {
                    print("\(error.localizedDescription)")
                }
                return
            }
//            let userId = googleUser.userID                  // For client-side use only!
            let idToken = googleUser.authentication.idToken // Safe to send to the server
            let email = googleUser.profile.email

            if googleUser.profile.hasImage{
                let imageUrl = googleUser.profile.imageURL(withDimension: 120)
                print(" image url: ", imageUrl?.absoluteString ?? "NO URL")
            }

            let user : User = User(id: 1, name: googleUser.profile.givenName, surname: googleUser.profile.familyName, imgName: ""  , email: googleUser.profile.email)

            print("email: ",email ?? "NO EMAIL")

            foo(idToken! , user)
        }
    }
}



#if DEBUG
struct SomeRepView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        GoogleSignInButtonView().environmentObject(LoginViewModel())
    }
}
#endif
```

Answer (score 18):

This is a part of my code where I implement Facebook and Google login, using any button I hope it helps you

```
import SwiftUI
import GoogleSignIn
import FBSDKLoginKit

var body: some View {
    LoadingView(isShowing: .constant(loading)) {
        NavigationView {
            ScrollView {
                VStack {

                    Text("Or Login with").font(.footnote)

                    HStack {
                        Button(action: self.logginFb, label: {
                            Image("ic_facebook").foregroundColor(Color.white).frame(width: 20, height: 20)
                        })
                                .padding(EdgeInsets(top: 8, leading: 16, bottom: 8, trailing: 16))
                                .background(Color("facebook"))
                                .cornerRadius(8.0)

                        Button(action: self.socialLogin.attemptLoginGoogle, label: {
                            Image("ic_google").frame(width: 20, height: 20)
                        })
                                .padding(EdgeInsets(top: 8, leading: 16, bottom: 8, trailing: 16))
                                .background(Color.white)
                                .cornerRadius(8.0)
                                .shadow(radius: 4.0)


                    }.padding()
                }.padding(.all, 32)
            }.navigationBarTitle(Text("Login"))
        }
    }
}

    func logginFb() {
        socialLogin.attemptLoginFb(completion: { result, error in

        })
    }


struct SocialLogin: UIViewRepresentable {

    func makeUIView(context: UIViewRepresentableContext<SocialLogin>) -> UIView {
        return UIView()
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIView, context: UIViewRepresentableContext<SocialLogin>) {
    }

    func attemptLoginGoogle() {
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance()?.presentingViewController = UIApplication.shared.windows.last?.rootViewController
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance()?.signIn()
    }

    func attemptLoginFb(completion: @escaping (_ result: FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult?, _ error: Error?) -> Void) {
        let fbLoginManager: FBSDKLoginManager = FBSDKLoginManager()
        fbLoginManager.logOut()
        fbLoginManager.logIn(withReadPermissions: ["email"], from: UIApplication.shared.windows.last?.rootViewController) { (result, error) -> Void in
            completion(result, error)
        }
    }

}

struct LoginView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        LoginView()
    }
}
```

The configuration of google and facebook in AppDelegate is the same as its documentation.

Now with swiftUI it is not necessary to use the default buttons that you give us.

Google and Facebook custom buttons
[image: Google and Facebook custom buttons]

Comment: I got an error, when I try to login, logout, then login again.

```First responder error: non-key window attempting reload - allowing due to manual```

Comment: GIDSignIn.sharedInstance()?.presentingViewController = UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.rootViewController

Answer (score 3):

Note for **SwiftUI 2.0 lifecycle**: there is no standard `AppDelegate` so you also need to add an adapter in main App file:

```
@main
struct ExampleApp: App {
    @UIApplicationDelegateAdaptor(ExampleAppDelegate.self) var appDelegate
```

and prepare the Delegate in a separate file:

```
//No @UIApplicationMain
class ExampleAppDelegate: NSObject, UIApplicationDelegate, GIDSignInDelegate {
  func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().clientID = "YOUR CLINET ID"
    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().delegate = self

    return true
  }

...
```

Comment: GIDSignInDelegate has been deprecated: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68395772/cannot-find-type-gidsignindelegate-in-scope

Answer (score 1):

With the latest SwiftUI, you can setup the `GIDSignInDelegate` within your `AppDelegate` and ensure that it conforms to all methods. Then, within your `SceneDelegate`, when setting up the window, you can drop this line in to setup the presenting view controller:

`GIDSignIn.sharedInstance()?.presentingViewController = window.rootViewController`.

Lastly, when creating your button, set the action or tap gesture to call `GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signIn()` and you *should* be good to go!

Comment: GIDSignInDelegate has been deprecated: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68395772/cannot-find-type-gidsignindelegate-in-scope

Answer (score 0):

GoogleSignIn 6.2.4 has the signIn function that requires a presenting UIViewController.

To solve this, add a sceneDelegate to the environment so it's accessible to SwiftUI.

**Set up an AppDelegate so we can hook up our SceneDelegate**

```
class AppDelegate: NSObject, UIApplicationDelegate {
    // Hook up our SceneDelegate
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, 
                     configurationForConnecting connectingSceneSession: UISceneSession, 
                     options: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) -> UISceneConfiguration {

        let configuration = UISceneConfiguration(name: nil, sessionRole: connectingSceneSession.role)
        if connectingSceneSession.role == .windowApplication {
            configuration.delegateClass = SceneDelegate.self
        }
    
        return configuration
    }
}
```

**Set up a SceneDelegate as an ObservableObject to keep track of the window**

```
// Set this up so we can access the window in the environment
class SceneDelegate: NSObject, ObservableObject, UIWindowSceneDelegate {
    var window: UIWindow?

    func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
        guard let windowScene = scene as? UIWindowScene else { return }
    
        self.window = windowScene.keyWindow
    }
}
```

**Be sure to enable the AppDelegate in the App**

```
@main
struct AdrichApp: App {
    @UIApplicationDelegateAdaptor(AppDelegate.self) var delegate

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}
```

**Finally, use it in a SwiftUI View to show your Continue with Google button**

```
struct SignInWithGoogle: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var sceneDelegate: SceneDelegate

    var body: some View {
        if let vc = sceneDelegate.window?.rootViewController {
            continueWithGoogle(config: GIDConfiguration(clientID: "YOUR CLINET ID"), presenter: vc)
        } else {
            emptyView
        }
    }
    
    private var emptyView: some View {
        print("Unable to access the root view controller")
        return EmptyView()
    }
    
    private func continueWithGoogle(config: GIDConfiguration, presenter: UIViewController) -> some View {
        Button {
            GIDSignIn.sharedInstance.signIn(with: config, presenting: presenter) { user, error in
                if let error = error {
                    print(error)
                    return
                }
                
                guard
                    let authentication = user?.authentication,
                    let idToken = authentication.idToken
                else {
                    return
                }
                
                let credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(withIDToken: idToken, accessToken: authentication.accessToken)

                // they are now signed in with Google!
            }
        } label: {
            Text("Continue with Google")
        }
    }
}
```