# Cannot find type GIDSignInDelegate in scope

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, swiftui

As you see in the below, I am getting these errors, I have installed Firebase and GoogleSignIn, what am I doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: Clean your project/derived data, if using CocoaPods, reinstall your pods, rebuild, and try again.

Comment: I did that already. Didn't work

Comment: I ran into the same problem today after updating my pod files. If you updated your GoogleSignIn pod to 6.0.0, you can either bump it back to a previous version (ie, pod 'GoogleSignIn', '~> 5.0.2'), or migrate your code according to this link.
https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/quick-migration-guide

Comment: Need the 6.0.0 for arm64 support but thank you

Comment: @JasonMartinez if you get Google SignIn working with Firebase, could you share a simple project setup with just that one sign-in button working, I'm super lost with the official guide: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/google-signin#swift_3

(I'm noob with iOS)

Comment: Visit this link to get the best solution to resolve this. https://stackoverflow.com/a/70984618/10635425

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As pointed out by Chris in the comments, follow the [migration guide](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/quick-migration-guide) to update to GoogleSignIn 6.x.

See also [this example](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-ios/pull/1222) of migrating the Firebase Auth QuickStart.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using latest GoogleSignIn sdk use this below code on button action

```
        let signInConfig = GIDConfiguration.init(clientID: KGoogle.clientID)

    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance.signIn(with: signInConfig, presenting: self) { user, error in
        guard error == nil else { return }
        guard let user = user else { return }

        if let profiledata = user.profile {
            
            let userId : String = user.userID ?? ""
            let givenName : String = profiledata.givenName ?? ""
            let familyName : String = profiledata.familyName ?? ""
            let email : String = profiledata.email
            
            if let imgurl = user.profile?.imageURL(withDimension: 100) {
                let absoluteurl : String = imgurl.absoluteString
                //HERE CALL YOUR SERVER API
            }
        }
        
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

pod 'GoogleSignIn', '~> 5.0.2'

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).